# SQLite & Linq - how can I visually design the .dbml file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, sqlite

SQLite first timer, and I want to use Linq for data access.

I made a SQLite database with sqliteadmin, and added it as a data source in VS2008. 
The problem is that when i try to drag&drop a table from the server explorer to the .dbml file, i get the error:

> "The selected object(s) use an
>   usupported data provider."

I used .NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite when i defined the data connection.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Linq-to-SQL can only be used with SQL Server databases

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL doesn't support SQLite, but it looks like [this SQLite provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) supports the Entity Framework, so you should be able to use [LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx).